# how to retrieve the old code from php file in pspad editor

Tags: file, reload, recovery, data-retrieval, pspad

I am using PsPad Editor for coding purpose in windows.

Some portion of code was deleted unfortunately. How to retrieve the old contents of my code ?

I have PsPad project file(.ppr). Is it useful for recover ?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete some code unfortunately, while the file is still opened in PSPad and not saved, you can revert all changes to previously saved version.

Use File / Open SPECIAL / recent / Reopen active file.

The .ppr file is not useful for recovery purposes.